# Am I just asking wrong?

Tags: support, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I've asked 5 questions since may and got no answers at all. I've been as specific as possible included as many details as possible and generally tried to make my question answerable.

So I can only conclude that I am doing something wrong. But as to what... no idea.

Answer (score 10):

I just gave a once over to all your questions. 3 of them seem to be basically bug reports where the software isn't just working how it's supposed to, there's not much we can generally do with those as we can't really get the diagnostic information from your system, so for those you should probably file a bug: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

One question was 3 paragraphs to ask what you wanted to ask, so I edited it down to get to the point quicker and made the title more descriptive.

The one about your sound card could be improved by linking to the questions that you've seen so far on other internet resources, while they may be confusing to you they could give answerers with more experience crucial information to help you.

And finally, nearly none of your questions have been touched since May, and generally speaking as you improve questions over time and add the results of your research they become better questions and get bumped, and get more attention, so I recommend that you keep updating your question with more information over time to ensure it doesn't get buried!

Answer (score 3):

I am definitely not the best person to give an answer (look at the answer counts on my questions), but maybe it is a consolation that you are not quite alone.

One thing that comes to my mind: Your questions have relatively few "views", which leads to the conclusion that the **Titles** of your questions induce only few people to actually look at the questions themselves.

**I** try to formulate Titles as real questions (which is the purpose of a Q&A site) - not as statements/descriptions.